# How to change color for point in UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage

I have a code that changes the color of a certain point in an image to transparent.

```
func processByPixel(in image: UIImage, byPoint: CGPoint) -> UIImage? {
    guard let inputCGImage = image.cgImage else { print("unable to get cgImage"); return nil }
    let colorSpace       = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let width            = inputCGImage.width
    let height           = inputCGImage.height
    let bytesPerPixel    = 4
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerRow      = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitmapInfo       = RGBA32.bitmapInfo


    guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else {
        print("Cannot create context!"); return nil
    }
    context.draw(inputCGImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

    guard let buffer = context.data else { print("Cannot get context data!"); return nil }

    let pixelBuffer = buffer.bindMemory(to: RGBA32.self, capacity: width * height)

    let offset = Int(byPoint.x) * width + Int(byPoint.y)
    pixelBuffer[offset] = .transparent

    let outputCGImage = context.makeImage()!
    let outputImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputCGImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

    return outputImage
}
```

By tapping on the picture, I calculate the point on which it was clicked and pass it to this function.
The problem is that the color changes slightly with the offset.
For example I will pass CGPoint(x: 0, y:0) but change color to 0, 30

I think that the offset variable is not calculated correctly

Comment: I think it should be `(y*width) + x` (number of vertical lines times line length plus x). But I don't see how this would cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: My guess is your input point is not what you think. Maybe it is in the wrong coordinate system.

Comment: If the image is shown in an image view, you have to map the tap point to compensate for the content mode.

Comment: @Roman Gorbatko Glad to hear that. I turned this into a proper answer so please consider marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the offset like this:

```
    let offset = Int(byPoint.y) * width + Int(byPoint.x)
```

It is the number of vertical lines times line length plus x.